# Error while deploying Gatsby Website to Amplify - could not resolve module "@parcel/namer-default"

Tags: amazon-web-services, gatsby, aws-amplify

I'm trying to deploy my **Gatbsy Website** to **AWS Amplify**, but on the build stage I encounter this error:

> Could not resolve module "@parcel/namer-default" from "/codebuild/output/src355497797/src/[MY-PACKAGE-NAME]/node_modules/@gatsbyjs/parcel-namer-relative-to-cwd/lib/index.js".

I've already tried to change the node version, both on Amplify and by creating a .nvmrc file in my project, but it didn't work.

Here is the longer error message:

````
2022-07-04T08:08:54.261Z [WARNING]: error Failed to compile Gatsby files (Error):
                                    Could not resolve module "@parcel/namer-default" from "/codebuild/output/src355497797/src/the-daily-bond/node\_modules/@gatsbyjs/parcel-namer-relative-to-cwd/lib/index.js".
2022-07-04T08:08:54.263Z [INFO]: not finished compile gatsby files - 0.860s
2022-07-04T08:08:55.028Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2022-07-04T08:08:55.134Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected```
````

Comment: Update: by updating node to the latest version, this error has now disappeared, but now another one pops up: `lmdb-darwin-x64 not accessible from @parcel/cache:lmdb`

Answer (score 3):

Without updating the node I was able to fix the problem by installing:

```
"@parcel/core": "^2.6.2",
"@parcel/namer-default": "^2.5.0",
```

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/35952

You can try just with @parcel/core

Comment: Thanks, this resolved the issue for me.  Strangely I only needed `/core` to get it working locally, but I also needed `/namer-default` to get it to build on Netlify.